# Android : Can't it possible to control 2+ activities data loading through a single timer 

Tags: android, performance, timer

i have 4 activities .In each activity one Timer i used to load data every minute. now i am using 4 timer s in 4 activities. Now what i want is ,is it possile to control all 4 activities data loading from one timer.? if possile means give an example for this.

Thanks....

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it in the background and push the updates to your activities either by updating the GUI directly or implanting the Observer pattern.

I have now a fully working example which might help you out. Ok first create an Observable class, something like this:

```
public class MyObservable extends Observable {

    int n = 0;

    public void setValue(int n) {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(n);
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return n;
    }
}
```

And create a Task, you have to correct parameterize yours, I'm just lazy :)

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask
{
    MyObservable observable;
    int numberOfNotifications = 0;

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            this.observable = (MyObservable) params[0];         
            while (true) {
                numberOfNotifications++;
                int timeSinceLastUpdate = 1000*5;
                Thread.sleep(timeSinceLastUpdate);
                publishProgress(numberOfNotifications);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {     
        observable.setValue((Integer) values[0]);
    }
}
```

Then you can extends the Application class and start the thread there:

```
public class StackApplication extends Application {

    private static MyObservable myObservable;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        myObservable = new MyObservable();
        new MyTask().execute(myObservable);
    }

    public static MyObservable getObservable() {
        return myObservable;
    }

}
```

One thing to note here is the singelton pattern to ensure you only get one instance of the Observable. 
Then it's piece of cake to implement the Observer in your relevant activities:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements Observer {   

    TextView tvCounter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tvCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);

        StackApplication.getObservable().addObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
        int i = (Integer) data;
        tvCounter.setText(Integer.toString(i));
    }
}
```

This should work, and if you wont to use this pattern in another Activity just remember to add the Observer and override the update method. Please comment if you get it working or have some problems using the example.

Comment: but here, one timer can control 4 activities .? i mean, common timer to all 4 activities to load data

Comment: Yes you can then implement the Observer in the 4 activities or update the 4 Activities directly. I would go for the Observer my self need an example for that?

Comment: hi i am trying but,i am not getting how to use observer class and how to use timer in it and how to update UI from it. a litle bit confusion in that. a small clarification from you is very usefull for me...

Comment: I've given a more full example you might look at